# GAEUnit doesn't automatically refresh code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using [GAEUnit](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/) for unit testing my GAE app. However, anytime I make a change to my code (not the test case code, but actual app code) and rerun the tests, it doesn't use my newly updated code, but the previous version. I have to stop the app completely from the terminal by hitting control+c, then start it up again for the tests to take in my new code. Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest SDK has an issue with not reloading changed code, not specific to GAEUnit: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8383

Comment: I tried the solution recommended in the thread, but it did not work. What's another work around? I tried doing `[reload(__import__(name)) for name in sys.modules.keys()]` in the setUp method of the test class, but for some weird reason I get "no module named sys' even though I imported it..